# Cannot use Hyperledger-Composer behind Proxy

Tags: proxy, hyperledger-composer

I have seen a lot of topics showing how so use HyperledgerComposer behind Proxy, but I just cannot make it work. It shows mit errors when I start the network or in the background when it tries to get the sample networks . I did the proxy entry in the local /root/.npmrc file and also some hints from: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3852
But it still does not work.

Has anyone managed to get this working behind the Proxy ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this in the Composer Knowledge Wiki - it should help you diagnose and fix your problem: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#startissues

Comment: Hi. I have seen that the composer need to have a full DNS resolution, and they have ti and also in connection.json is everything on default. I have another server that is not behind proxy with the default install and everything works great there. I have seen the article and this is what I have:

Comment: root@server01:~# cat /root/.composer/cards/PeerAdmin@hlfv1/connection.json
{"name":"hlfv1","x-type":"hlfv1","x-commitTimeout":300,"version":"1.0.0","client":{"organization":"Org1","connection":{"timeout":{"peer":{"endorser":"300","eventHub":"300","eventReg":"300"},"orderer":"300"}}},"channels":{"composerchannel":{"orderers":["orderer.example.com"],"peers":{"peer0.org1.example.com":{}}}},"organizations":{"Org1":

Comment: {"mspid":"Org1MSP","peers":["peer0.org1.example.com"],"certificateAuthorities":["ca.org1.example.com"]}},"orderers":{"orderer.example.com":{"url":"grpc://localhost:7050"}},"peers":{"peer0.org1.example.com":{"url":"grpc://localhost:7051","eventUrl":"grpc://localhost:7053"}},"certificateAuthorities":{"ca.org1.example.com":{"url":"http://localhost:7054","caName":"ca.org1.example.com"}}}